# regarding the use of new Constraint in c#

Tags: c#

i never use new Constraint because the use is not clear to me. here i found one sample but i just do not understand the use. here is the code

```
class ItemFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class ItemFactory2<T> where T : IComparable, new()

{
}
```

so anyone please make me understand the use of new Constraint with small & easy sample for real world use. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9002928/95573), something like this would fail because `Bar` does not have a parameterless constructor

```
   class ItemFactory<T> where T : new()
   {
      public T GetNewItem()
      {
         return new T();
      }
   }

   class Foo : ItemFactory<Bar>
   {

   }

   class Bar
   {
      public Bar(int a)
      {

      }
   }
```

Actual error is: `'Bar' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ItemFactory<T>'`

The following would also fail:

```
class ItemFactory<T>
{
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Actual error is: `Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint`

Comment: i just need to know that...new() will be always use for parameter less constructor. if constructor take parameter then we can not use syntax like where T : new() ? please discuss. thanks

Answer (score 14):

This constraint requires that the generic type that is used is non-abstract and that it has a default (parameterless) constructor allowing you to call it.

Working example:

```
class ItemFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

which obviously now will force you to have a parameterless constructor for the type that is passed as generic argument:

```
var factory1 = new ItemFactory<Guid>(); // OK
var factory2 = new ItemFactory<FileInfo>(); // doesn't compile because FileInfo doesn't have a default constructor
var factory3 = new ItemFactory<Stream>(); // doesn't compile because Stream is an abstract class
```

Non-working example:

```
class ItemFactory<T>
{
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T(); // error here => you cannot call the constructor because you don't know if T possess such constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: Default ctor is empty ctor ;)

Comment: @Novakov: Not correct. The default ctor is a ctor without parameters. But it's body doesn't need to be empty, it very well can contain code.

Comment: @Daniel: I always thought that default ctor is ctor generated by compiler if no ctor is defined and 'default' means that is has default (call base class ctor) behavior.

Comment: @Novakov: You are partly correct: If your class doesn't define a constructor itself, the compiler generates a constructor that has no parameters, does nothing and calls the default constructor of the base class. That's correct. However, the term "default constructor" means all constructors that are (1) public and (2) have no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor.

quoted from the official [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can read `new()` as if it is an interface with a constructor. Just like that IComparable specifies that the type T has a method CompareTo, the new constraint specifies that the type T has a public constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the constraint acts on `<T>` in the class declaration. In the first case, it requires that the generic `T` object has a default (parameterless) constructor. In the second example, it requires that `T` should have a default, parameterless constructor and that it must implement the `IComparable` interface.